# react.js website and when moving page and refresh cant find react router page and show 404 error

Tags: reactjs, github, visual-studio-code, page-refresh, custom-error-pages

i have deployed and host on github pages my website - moshedavidovbarber.hair that it the url name
you can go and see the problem when i click on one of the navbar option to go another page everything works until you refresh the page then i get 404 error , if you refresh the page on the homepage it works and doesn't send 404 error . im attaching also photos of the code i wrote if you could help me it will be very helpful !

i have deployed and host on github pages my website - moshedavidovbarber.hair that it the url name
you can go and see the problem when i click on one of the navbar option to go another page everything works until you refresh the page then i get 404 error , if you refresh the page on the homepage it works and doesn't send 404 error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lypv5.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.